# Markov's Inequality

Tags: probability, inequality

The Markov's inequality is

$$\mathbb{P}(X > x) \leq \frac{\mathbb{E}(X^m)}{x^m},$$
where $X \in (0,1)$.

I have read that the tightest upper bound is obtained by choosing optimum $m$ as a function of $x$. What does exactly this mean and how should we optimize over $m$?

EDIT: In my case,
$$\mathbb{P}(X > x) \leq \frac{\exp(-Am^{a})}{x^m},$$ where $A$ is a positive constant and $a \in (0,1)$. In this case, what will be the optimum $m$ which gives the tightest bound?

Comment: The right side is a function of m, depending also on the distribution of X. You can try to find its minimum using the usual methods. This will give the best estimate that Markov ' inequality could give you.

Comment: Thanks. I thought so. I have edited the question to now provide exact expression of the $m$th moment.

Comment: Your moment estimate makes no sense unless X is confined to (0,1), in which case you should be focused on x in (0,1).

Comment: Yes. That is the case. I missed to mention it. Indeed $X \in (0,1)$.

Comment: You can rewrite your right side as $x^{-Am^a/\ln (x)-m} $. For x in (0,1) this is minimized when the exponent is maximized, which does occur since x and a are both in (0,1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take the derivative of the right hand side with respect to $m$:

$$\frac{d}{dm}\exp(-Am^a - m\ln x) =  \exp(-Am^a - m\ln x)\cdot(-Aam^{a-1} - \ln x)$$

Assuming $m\in (0, \infty),$ the bound will take on its extremal value at one of the boundaries (i.e. $m = 0$ or $\infty$), or where that derivative equals zero (i.e. $m(x) = (\frac{-Aa}{\ln x})^{\frac{1}{1-a}}$). Note that $m=0$ is the limit for $x \to 0$, and $m = \infty$ is the limit for $x \to 1$. Also note that $\frac{1}{1-a} > 0 $, so the power is well-defined and real-valued.